# Installing numpy 1.21.0 or earlier

Tags: python, numpy, python-wheel

I am looking to run a tslearn package - however, it throws an error on importing:

> "Numba needs NumPy 1.21 or less"

When I attempt to install Numpy 1.21 via the command line

```
pip install numpy==1.21.00
```

I get gigantic error code, ending in (full error code see at the bottom):

> "Could not build wheels for numpy ..."

I have the most recent pip, wheels etc.; I also have the Virtual Studio installer.

I have tried using .whl files from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy); however, for version 1.19.5 or earlier, none of these are compatible with my Python 3.10 version; so I get the error

> "... .whl is not a supported wheel on this platform".

---

Full error code:

```
C:\Users\job adam>pip install numpy==1.21.0
Collecting numpy==1.21.0
  Using cached numpy-1.21.0.zip (10.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [214 lines of output]
      setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.0 may not yet support Python 3.10.
        warnings.warn(
      Running from numpy source directory.
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
      Cythonizing sources
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      blis_info:
        libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
        NOT AVAILABLE

      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_info:
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4kzvzfqg\numpy_f6853e8c77184442a05886c6b71413e0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_info:
        libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4kzvzfqg\numpy_f6853e8c77184442a05886c6b71413e0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4kzvzfqg\numpy_f6853e8c77184442a05886c6b71413e0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
        NOT AVAILABLE

      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_clapack_info:
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      flame_info:
        libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\lib
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\lib
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\lib
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_info:
        libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\job adam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4kzvzfqg\numpy_f6853e8c77184442a05886c6b71413e0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4kzvzfqg\numpy_f6853e8c77184442a05886c6b71413e0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        NOT AVAILABLE

      numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
        FOUND:
          language = c
          define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

      Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
      C:\Users\job adam\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m19c4jn7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: You should provide the whole error, because it's harder to understand the source of the problem without it.

Comment: What happens with `pip install numpy`?  (without specifying version).  Do you already have a working `numpy`?

Comment: That works, and yes, I do.

Comment: I can't speak for your case, but for me, pip installing `numba` automatically installs a compatible `numpy` (1.21.5), removing my existing `1.22`.  You are in a windows world, where as I'm linux/ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by downgrading to Python 3.6 (completely uninstalling Python 3.10) and using this to install Pandas 1.19.5 via pip.